# How to get the reversed route of a WebSocket in Play2.0

Tags: scala, routes, playframework, playframework-2.0

In html templates if I give this:

```
@routes.Application.chat(username).webSocketURL()
```

I get that:

```
ws://localhost:9000/room/chat?username=test
```

I want a way to get this as a string in a scala class.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaRouting), use:

```
controllers.routes.chat(username).webSocketURL()
```

Comment: nope it does not work for websocket, I add a nearly empty template instead.

Comment: @shenshei could you please update the question with the code you are using and what you are getting?